# angular $compile and passing variable to directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that accepts a variable...

```
scope: {
            tasks: '='
        }
```

I'm doing this...

```
compiled = $compile(template)(scope);
element.append(compiled);
```

How do I set the tasks argument on the directive?

Thanks

Comment: We probably also need to see the template to answer this properly. What I can say is that the template needs something like `<... ng-tasks="expression">` to work properly.

Comment: *"How do I set the tasks argument on the directive?"* What does it mean?

Comment: @dfsq The purpose of isolate scopes on directives is to allow for parameterized, reusable directives. In that regard, using the word "argument" by analogy to a function's argument is not fundamentally inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

First, your template has to have an element in it with your directive on it, so for example,

```
var template = '<div my-directive></div>';
```

Second, that element must also have an attribute whose name is the one specified in your directive's isolated scope definition, with camelCase replaced by that other case with dashes:

```
// If you used the simple syntax { tasks: '=' }
var template = '<div my-directive tasks="something"></div>';

// If you used the syntax { tasks: '=fancyName' }
var template = '<div my-directive fancy-name="something"></div>';
```

Finally, the compiled template `$compile(template)` must be evaluated with a `scope` that has a `something` property in it! That should be it, hope I didn't forget anything.